# Eliminar valores repetidos en una consulta con STRING_AGG() en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estaba probando una consulta en SQL en la cual necesito concatenar unos valores en forma de lista separada por comas, y funciona, solo tengo el problema de los valores duplicados.

Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT t0.id_marcas, 
       t0.nombremarcas, 
       t0.orden, 
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(t2.name,  ', ') AS Descripcion 
        FROM  exlcartu_devcit.exl_store_to_cuisine t1 
               INNER JOIN exlcartu_devcit.exl_cuisine t2 
                       ON t1.cuisine_id = t2.cuisine_id 
        WHERE  store_id = (SELECT store_id 
                           FROM   exlcartu_devcit.exl_store 
                           WHERE  id_marcas = t0.id_marcas 
                                  AND status = 1 
                           )) AS Descripcion, 
       (SELECT preparing_time 
        FROM   exlcartu_devcit.exl_store 
        WHERE  id_marcas = t0.id_marcas 
               AND status = 1 
        )                     AS Tiempo, 
       t0.imagenmarcas, 
       t0.logo, 
       t0.imagen 
FROM   exlcartu_devcit.exl_marcas t0
```

Pensaba que la solucion podria ser solo agregar un DISTINCT a la consulta para evitar los valores repetidos de esta manera...

```
(SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT (t2.name),  ', ') AS Descripcion
```

Pero al parecer la funcion STRING_AGG() no lo soporta, alguna idea de como evitar los valores repetidos?

Comment: Puedes usar un Group by y un HAVING para que no traiga los repetidos

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Sabes la estructuracion?